# Spring Cloud Consul Configuration with SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I am configuring Consul with SpringBoot and found a [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/1.0.x/index.html) here. Even browsed other resources, no more additional configs or scenarios found.

Therefore, I am curious whether only those configurations are available when springboot app is integrated with consul. I would like to deep dive and Can anyone let me know any other properties available ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the properties available.

[image]

[image]

These are used in 
`org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulConfigProperties`, `org.springframework.cloud.consul.discovery.ConsulDiscoveryProperties`.

Best place to see which property is being used where is to see AutoConfiguration of any module. For example for Mongo check `MongoAutoConfiguration`  and `MongoDataAutoConfiguration`. Similarly, for consul check `ConsulAutoConfiguration`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I know any workaround to see these props?

Comment: You should check `org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulConfigProperties`, `org.springframework.cloud.consul.discovery.ConsulDiscoveryProperties`

Answer (score 0):

This page will provide configuration properties

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

In addition, you can see the config properties in your IDE itself. If you are using IntelliJ or STS/Eclipse, go to application.yml file, you can view and see the configurations available by pressing Ctrl + space . It will give suggestions.